# Rules of thumb for auxiliary verbs (avoir/être) in passé composé?

Tags: verbes, allemand, auxiliaires, passé-composé, rule-of-thumb

Can someone point to some strict rules or rules of thumb for using *être/avoir* for *passé composé* for irregular verbs? Does it follow from change of radical for different tense?

In German, a change of the radical vowel means, you have to use *avoir*. But there are also some verbs, for which one can use either *avoir* or *être* to build *Perfect*, or at least one usage is more common in the south and the other in the north region of Germany. A rough rule in German and in general Germanic languages is that "weak verbs" and intransitive verbs mostly need *être* to build the perfect as far as I know. But French has 3 times as many irregular verbs as German, so maybe there are very different rules. Are my hints and assumptions above a good start?

PS: [This site](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/HabenSein.html) lists the rules for German verbs very accurately (in German).

Comment: “A change of the radical vowel means, you have to use *avoir*”. I don't think there's any kind of rule like that, or I don't know what you mean by “A change of the radical vowel”. “Ich *habe* geschr*ie*ben.” and “Ich *bin* gebl*ie*ben.” Anything that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Btw, I think the correspondence between German and French is very strong with this respect. There are only a few exceptions including some “movement-related” verbs that have close but different usages, like *fahren* (go with a car, etc.) vs *conduire* (use a wheel, etc.), which explain the difference in the choice of the auxiliary. Of course passive is the most recurrent (but consistent) difference “*sein _ worden*” vs “*avoir été _*”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I read an older rule going "Ich singe - Ich sang - Ich habe gesungen - radical vowel change i - o - u" It makes sense to me that in very past tense was maybe more expressed by phonetic change than nowadays with auxiliary verbs, but thats just my guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison with German is not going to be very helpful, in general. Here are rules of thumb for French:

1. All reflexive and reciprocal verbs are conjugated with `être`
2. Most of the rest of the verbs are conjugated with `avoir`
3. Except for a short list of verbs, which, when used intransitively, are conjugated with `être`

The rule of thumb for the short list is that they generally indicate some motion or movement. They are often assembled into a mnemonic diagram called "la maison d'être" such as you can easily find on the web ([like here](http://faculty.virginia.edu/ajmlevine/shared/maisondetre.html)).

[image: An image replacing the dead link above]

It is worth it to simply memorize this list since the same rules apply not only to Passé Composé but to all compound tenses.

Comment: To complement this answer, here's **[a flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9McJ.png)** of the decision tree.